# Extruding a cylinder with complex UV mapping

Tags: opengl, 3d, primitive, uv-mapping

This is all being done programmatically, not with any kind of 3D editor.

I am being delivered a shape like this:
[image: top of cylinder]

The UV coordinates that map that checkerboard are just the x,y coordiates of the shape, but I can count on anything I want to map onto this being 1.0,1.0 in size.

Now, my job is to extrude a cylinder from this shape, programmatically.  Easy enough:

[image: Extruded cylinder]

I just took the UV coordinates from the top and kept them on the vertex on the bottom.  But now, the spec says that the final cylinder should look something like this (this is mocked up, I have not been able to generate it):

[image]

I thought I was just going to tweak my UV coordinates to account for the height, and get checkers on the side, but what I end up getting is a swirled texture like this:

[image]

I understand why.  I created that by just adding n to the V coordinate.  But since the v coordinate isn't always on a checker boundary when it gets extruded down, it ends up like the image.

I believe I need some kind of directional vector to add the UV coordinate at the bottom of the cylinder to make the side checkers straight, but everything I try produces a worse mess.

How could I UV map those sides correctly?

Comment: Please no c++ tag without asking about specific c++ code you have.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you're having is that the texture for the cylinder top (and bottom) doesn't determine the texture for the side. And I don't think there's any general solution to that problem. You'll need to be given "an extrusion texture" to apply to the side. You can't produce that from the one for the ends.

I'm not sure how general your algorithm is supposed to be. Does it need to work for any texture or just a specific one?

But here's an approach that might help. Let's assume that your texture is only two colors and that you're given a distance w that defines the length along the side for which the color is constant. Let's assume the desired texture inverts for each distance w down the cylinder. There is no way to derive this length in general. It has to be given. But if you have it, you can "solve" the problem (as I understand it, which might not be accurate).

First step is to produce the inverted texture. Assuming the texture is only two colors, this should be relatively straightforward.

Then divide the side length of the cylinder into segments of length w. For each segment apply either the original texture or the inverted one using your original uv map.

I don't know if there's any easy way to use two different textures (as specified by two different image files) in this manner. If not, the original and inverted textures can be combined into a single texture file using different image areas for each and then the uv coordinates computed appropriately.

If I've misunderstood, or understood correctly but am otherwise wrong, I apologize and would like to be corrected.

Comment: Fundamentally, you were correct.  There was no mathematical solution to this problem.  After I got past that, I worked out a solution where it finds where (on the rim) the checkers changed and produces a U coordinate around the sides based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine unwrapping a cylinder (for the sake of simplicity, forget about the top and bottom caps). Aren't you left with a rectangle? Now, let us think how the horizontal and vertical coordinates are calculated.

When you're calculating the radians of your ellipse (base shape of your cylinder) you also calculate the U mapping coords. What you still need are the coordinates in the V direction: the bottom of your cylinder could be the `v0` and the top the `v1` coordinate.

```
  |< 0..2*PI >|

u0,v1       u1,v1
  x-----------x   ---
  | | | | | | |    ^
  | | | | | | |  height (extrusion length)
  | | | | | | |    v
  x-----------x   ---
u0,v0       u1,v0
```

**Formally:**

```
radian_delta = 2*PI / num_slices;
height_delta = height / num_segments;

u_coord = (slice_index * radian_delta) / (2*PI);
v_coord = (segment_index * height_delta) / height;
```

---

**Addendum**

I've overlooked the fact, that you're not calculating the coords by yourself (you get them from somewhere else) and your intent is to calculate the u-coord from the existing uv-coords. For that, we'll have to take the arctanget (`atan2`) of each uv-coordinate to get the angle (in radians).

The return value of `atan2` is in the range `[-PI, PI]`. Since we need the range `[0, 2*PI]` to map the result to the range `[0, 1]`, all you have to do is to add `PI` to the result and divide by `2*PI` or `atan2(v, u) / (2 * PI) + 0.5`.

Depending on your number of height segments, the v-coord is simply the y-coord of the vertex (mapped to the range `[0, 1]`). In case of just the bottom and top caps, that would be either `0` or `1`.

**Pseudocode:**

```
foreach vertex in ellipse
do
    radian  := atan2(vertex.v, vertex.u) + PI;
    u_coord := radian / (2 * PI);
end
```

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer.  I think my problem is, I'm given the cylinder top.  I am expected to take the UV coordinate at a certain location and extrude it downward.  Ideally, on my cylinder sides, I start with V=0 at the top and V=n at the bottom, but then that leaves me an issue of converting the uv coordinates of the top at the rim, and turning that into a use u,0.0f.  I can sort of make that work except that I can't make a consistent uv->u equation that will wrap around correctly.

Comment: Like, picture that I have to poke a needle through the top of that.  Where I poke the needle, I have a UV.  Now somehow that needs to be turned into a segment that starts at u,0 and ends at u,0+height... such that the next poked segment (around the rim) will also be consistent with the uv->u transformation.

Comment: @KiraHoneybee `atan2(v, u) -> [-pi, +pi]`

Comment: Thank you for the additional assistance.  I think I might be very close to solving this, but burnout might be preventing me from thinking straight.  When extruding the sides, I am setting the new vertex uv to be (atan2f(utop,vtop),0.0f) ... however I am utterly at a loss as to how to apply the ellipse radius to this (utop,vtop are already the xy values of the radius).  Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know in which language you're programming but the parameter sequence to `atan2` is mostly (y, x) or in this case (v, u) -> `y` before `x`. Now, as described above, the U-coordinates of the cylinder mantle is based on the angle (in radians), as are the UV-coordinates of the ellipse. But rather than calculating the `sin` and `cos` of the angle (in radians, where a radian is nothing more than a fraction of the circumference), we want the angle of the `x` and `y` (or `uv`) coordinates, which can be done by the `atan2` function.

Comment: Once you have the angle (radian), you have the u-coord. The v-coord is simply the y-coord of the vertex (of the mantle, not the ellipse), mapped to a range between `0` and `1`.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252250/discussion-between-kirahoneybee-and-erdal-kucuk).